# ng-style change background when condition is true

Tags: angularjs

I want both the background of the div and the label text to change when power is more than 5. How can I achieve this in angular?

```
<div flex="5" layout="column" layout-align="center center center" class="default" ng-style="{'background-color':power1.value >5 ?  'red': 'black'}">
                        <label><center>VOLTAGE1</center></label>
                        </div>
```

I want to use angular `ng-style` and `ng-class` to change the background color of my div when a value exceed 5 and to also change the div label text below is sample of what i have it changes the color but how can change the text as well

Comment: i want to  also change the label text to voltage high when value is greater than 5 the background is changing with that ng-style but i need both the background and label to change

Comment: are you already settiing power in your controller?

Comment: you gave that voltage static.....so please provide relavent js

Comment: i have already set power and its working but now i would like to know how can i change the label text when power is greater than 5 i want the text to be voltage high

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you understand how to set the value for "power1" in your controller?

```
<div flex="5" layout="column" layout-align="center center center" class="default" ng-style="{'background-color': power1.value >5 ?  'red': 'black'}">
  <label>
   <center>{{power1.value >5 ?  'VOLTAGE HIGH': 'VOLTAGE1'}}</center>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: so in this center tag i should include any angular ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but the brackets are angular. It is not working for you?